# Kotlin generic value object serialization with GSON

Tags: serialization, kotlin, gson

For example I have the next classes

```
abstract class X<out T>(val x: T)

data class Y(val y: String = "y") : X<String>(x = "x")

class Holder(
     val  value: X<String>
)
```

I try to serialize with gson:

```
val gson = Gson()

val x = Holder(Y())
val json = gson.toJson(x)
```

I've got `{"value":{"x":"x"}}` but I need `{"value":{"x":"x", "y":"y"}}`

Comment: have you tried using [`toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-)?

Comment: @StefanGolubović yes, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem we need to use `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` from gson extras and to init gson like

```
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(
                    RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(X::class.java)
                            .registerSubtype(Y::class.java)
            )
            .create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Gson does not analyze the actual object class/type if the object type is known at the declaration site or specified in other way.
I don't do Kotlin, but this behavior can also be reproduced with good old Java:

```java
abstract class X<T> {
    private final T x;
    X(final T x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

final class Y extends X<String> {
    private final String y;
    Y(final String x, final String y) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }
}

final class Holder {
    private final X<String> value; // value is considered known in advance here
    Holder(final X<String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You have to add a type parameter to the `Holder` class, something like `Holder<T>` and `T value`, and specify the actual type parameterization before serialization/deserialization.

```java
gson.toJson(holder, new TypeToken<Holder<X<?>>>() {}.getType())
```

produces `{"value":{"x":"x"}}` (`X` is *known* to be the type here), but:

```java
gson.toJson(holder, new TypeToken<Holder<Y>>() {}.getType())
```

produces `{"value":{"y":"y","x":"x"}}`. Sorry have no idea how to do this in Kotlin.